# how to infer the return value type from std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, template-argument-deduction

I'd like to make the return value type generic using `std::function`, but it does not work, code:
debuggable code can be found: http://cpp.sh/5bk5

```
class Test
{
public:
  template <typename R, typename F = std::function<R()>>
  R f(F&& op) {
     op();
  }

  void t() {
    int a = 10;
    f([this, a]() { return "chars"; });
  }
};

int main()
{
   t::Test test;
   test.t();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe use `result_of` to get at the return type?

Comment: Have you tried using void*? That's the Cish way to have generic types.

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid the Template/`std::function` way and use `auto` for return type.

If you can compile C++14 it's easy

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>

class Test
 {
   public:
      Test(){ }

      template <typename F>
      auto f (F && op)
       { return op(); }

      void t()
       { std::cout << f([this]() { return "chars"; }) << std::endl; }
 };


int main()
 {
    Test test;

    test.t();

    return 0;
 }
```

If you can compile only C++11 you have to use `decltype()` for `Test::f()`

```
  template <typename F>
  auto f (F && op) -> decltype( op() )
   { return op(); }
```